# Can we upload posts on facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, upload, facebook-page

I have a Facebook profile and I will make it a page. Because of it I will lose all my data so I will  take a backup of my Facebook images and my post by Facebook tool. But I wonder if it is possible to upload my data in the new page.
These is any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so that there is a way. You will have to do this manually I guess..

Answer (score 0):

If you had the time you could use the Graph API to pull down the majority of posts from your [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and then use this data to reupload to the new [Page object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

Your question doesn't specify that you're looking for an API-based solution though, which wouldn't be a valid question for Stack Overflow. However, given the new Page timeline feature allows you to back-date posts on your Page wall, you should be able to manually add all your old content to your new page.